# XSLT 2.0 HOW TO PRINT SAME LINE multiple time based on concat column dates

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Assume following record is in xml

EmpNo name enrollingDates
123   abc  10/01/2022-10/02/2022-10/05/2022

Currently reocrd is coming in one line even when dates are different in enrollingdates column
We need to break it into three lines as follow

EmpNo Name enrollingDates
123   ABC  10/01/2022
123   ABC  10/02/2022
123   ABC  10/05/2022

We need to do it in xslt 2.0

Any help will be highly appreciated

I am new to xslt
I have not tried myself yet but if anyone of you can share your thoughts on it I will highly appreciate.

Comment: Please show the source xml and the expected result xml

Comment: Why would you need to do this in XSLT when the input is not XML (or so it seems)? It's not even clear what is the input - it could be tab-separated or fixed-length.

Comment: Input is in xml

Comment: <Employee>  <EmpNo>123<EmpNo> <Name>ABC<Name> <enrollingDates>10/02/2022-10/02/2022-10/02/2022 enrollingDates> </Employee>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: I am trying to edit question but it keeps giving an error

Answer (score 0):

Given a well-formed XML input such as:

```
<Employee>
  <EmpNo>123</EmpNo>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <enrollingDates>10/01/2022-10/02/2022-10/05/2022</enrollingDates>
</Employee>
```

you can apply the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:variable name="common" select="EmpNo, Name" />
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(enrollingDates, '-')">
        <Employee>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$common"/>
            <enrollingDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </enrollingDate>
        </Employee>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employee>
   <EmpNo>123</EmpNo>
   <Name>ABC</Name>
   <enrollingDate>10/01/2022</enrollingDate>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <EmpNo>123</EmpNo>
   <Name>ABC</Name>
   <enrollingDate>10/02/2022</enrollingDate>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <EmpNo>123</EmpNo>
   <Name>ABC</Name>
   <enrollingDate>10/05/2022</enrollingDate>
</Employee>
```

Note that the result in this example is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document (no single root element).

Comment: You understood the problem perfectly when I tried your solution it is giving me following error xml-22018 (error) Parse Error in tokensize function

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with that. You can see my code working without an error here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aUPRMF

Comment: Need output in text, will your code work?

Comment: @Rabit2 Please stop wasting everyone's time here. The proper way to ask a question is to post an example of the XML input, show your attempted code and add the expected output. You have done none of these things. I don't even know why I answered your question instead of voting to close it.

Comment: If two dates are same and one is different the output should be in two lines